# Origin - constant or new type?

Tags: c++, c++11, geometry

I was writing a `Point` class (in 3d space) and have been wondering what would be the best way to create the origin point. Here is the basic class (taken from Andy's example, just in case someone wondered what the basic implementation was):

```
struct Point
{
    constexpr Point(double x_, double y_, double z_) : x(x_), y(y_), z(z_) { }

    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
```

The first way to have the origin would be to define a `constexpr` variable:

```
constexpr Point origin = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
```

The second would be to define a new type and overload algorithmsif they can benefit from optimizations when computing with the origin (let's assume I wrote a `constexpr` constructor for `Point`):

```
struct Origin: public Point
{
    constexpr Origin():
        Point(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    {}
};
constexpr Origin origin;
```

While the first method seems simpler and less error-prone, I would like to know whether the second one looks like a good idea and whether it has some pitfalls I did not see.

**EDIT:** Thinking of reference libraries, I noticed that CGAL used something like that:

```
class Origin {};
const Origin ORIGIN;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> While the first method seems simpler and less error-prone, I would like to know whether the second one looks like a good idea and whether it has some pitfalls I did not see.

I think the inheritance-based design is conceptually flawed: you do not want to introduce a new type here, and the origin is conceptually an *instance* (a very special instance, but still an instance) of the `Point` class, not a specialization of that type.

I would rather add a static `constexpr` member function called `origin()` here:

```
struct Point
{
    constexpr Point(double x_, double y_, double z_) : x(x_), y(y_), z(z_) { }
    constexpr static Point origin() { return {0, 0, 0}; }

    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
```

You could then use that this way:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr Point o = Point::origin();
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a static data member of type `Point` called `origin` rather than having a static function called `origin()`. Which one to choose is mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: What about overloading critical algorithms for `Origin`? Would there be any way to have this advantage again with your solution? I know it logically should be an instance, but we can still get advantages with it being a type.

Comment: What are these critical algorithms that you mention?

Comment: @Jehan: Just use an `if (...)` to handle the case where the point being passed is the origin.

Comment: @Jehan: Moreover, `Point x(1, 2, 3); Point y(2, 4, 6); my_algorithm(2*x - y);`. Here `my_algorithm` will work with the origin, and the only way to detect it is through an `if (...)`.

Comment: @AndyProwl Yes, I already knew it would not change anything with a computed origin. That would just be a tool for the user when he really means he wants to use the origin and somehow benefit from it.

Comment: @Jehan: Just use an `if (...)` to handle the special case and give everybody the benefit. Really, a new type called `Origin` is conceptually unsound and using it the way you intend will become very cumbersome very soon. Just for fun, you may try and see it yourself. But in my team this would not pass code review ;)

Comment: @AndyProwl Actually, the end of my question is really "in which way could it be cumbersome"? I mean, the algorithms would of course check for `(0, 0, 0)` if needed and that little trick would not only pass the `if(...)` successfully, but also allow further optimization when needed, right? It is not meant to replace a proper check, but to give further possibilities. In this case, how bad can it be?

Comment: @Jehan: You mean, how bad can it be to have an `Origin` type, or how bad can it be to have an optimized algorithm for the origin which is executed conditionally after an `if (...)` check?

Comment: @AndyProwl I mean, how bad can be having the `Origin` type just for static checks (I don't intend to use it the body of non-specialized algorithms, that's just for the user to be able to call algorithms with `foobar(origin);` and benefit from the static check instead of the runtime one). It don't seem to break anything existing.

Comment: @Jehan: You normally introduce a sub-type if you want to specialize behavior or extend it. Here you are doing none of those things. The fact that a point is the origin should be a *precondition* of your specialized algorithm, and you shouldn't be trying to check that at compile time. I do not see how having a type `Origin` is going to help the programmer, mostly because in 99% of the situations I can think of, such algorithms would work on the result of some computation (and the result is a `Point`). And for the 1% when they would not, I think introducing such a fake type is just not worth it

Comment: @AndyProwl Well, I think I'll keep the "not worth it" part then :)
Ah, last question: should we blame CGAL for having `class Origin{}; const Origin ORIGIN`? :p

Comment: @Jehan: I don't know CGAL unfortunately, but I would tend to say "yes" ;) (unless `Origin` there means something else)

Comment: @AndyProwl It means nothing more, they just have `Origin` for `Point` and `Null_Vector` for `Vector`.

Comment: @Jehan: But AFAICT, `Origin` there does not derive from `Point` (still don't like it though)

Comment: No, it does not, which means that you do have to use overloaded algorithms, while I designed the one above to have the following behavior: "use specialized algorithm when it exists, act like a regular `Point` otherwise", which can be quite invisible for the user while allowing specialized algorithms.

Comment: @Jehan: As I said, I do not think it is worth it. Additionally, its interface allows you modifying an object of type `Origin` so that it is not an origin anymore (it uses public inheritance to derive from `Point`, and if it didn't, you wouldn't be able to treat it the way you intend). This design is a no-go for me.

Comment: @AndyProwl Well, at least, you know how to defend your ideas :)

Comment: @Jehan: It isn't always like that, but in this case I really think it I am defending the right idea ;) Good luck with your project

Comment: @AndyProwl It would be sad if you thought you were defending the wrong one :D
Oh, and I don't have any project, it was more like food for thought. But thanks anyway.